# Microsoft Bot Framework Attachment Size Limit

Tags: c#, botframework, skype

I'm writing a bot for my company which will take images and order numbers for our delivery drivers, and our MD wants to extend it to our employees with company cars.

I've got the whole thing nailed, with the exception of image attachments. Smaller stuff, like with the bog standard phones we give to the drivers (<1.5MB) are working fine, as well as other small test images I had.

Larger images like my Lumia 950XL takes, and that our employees with the better phones take (all >3.5MB) fail to download from the ContentURL that the channel provides.

This occurs on the Skype channel, and the Web Chat channel, so I imagine it will occur on all. Is there a way to increase the size limit, or an I stuck telling the users to lower the MP of their images?

For reference, the exception I'm getting is:

> This message caused the following error: A task was canceled.
>   StackTrace:
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>      at SkypeOrderBot.Dialogs.OrderNumberDialog.d__3.MoveNext() in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\SkypeOrderBot\SkypeOrderBot\Dialogs\OrderNumberDialog.cs:line 80

Comment: It could  limited by Skype etc. Try to do this with telegram, they have fixed known limit of 50 mb for bots

Comment: Are you suggesting that it's an issue with Skype sending the image?  If so, it's going to the bot fine, it's just when I try to read the byte array from the URL.  If not, I'm downloading Telegram now and trying it.

Comment: So post some code. U said that u go fine when sending small images and error when bigger, so i suggested that ii can be some platform specific restrictions.

Comment: Yeah, you'd be correct as well.  Telegram accepted the large image.  Cheers, I wouldn't have bothered checking Telegram, since we won't be using it.